# Run mysqldump commands locally in Windows

Tags: shell, encoding, utf-8, mysql

I try to run some **mysqldump** commands locally in **Windows** using `xampp` shell but the usual Linux server commands (which I'm used to) don't seem to exist in Windows.  For example: `cat` and `iconv` return an error.  Are there any equivalent commands in Windows?

I need to convert a database file into **UTF-8** and the only way to do it is via **mysqldump** because by default it dumps the data as `UTF-8`, (even when the data is stored in another encoding), and I need to use commands to output the database in its original encoding, then convert it to `UTF-8`.

First I need to convert the dump using `iconv` function:

```
cat dump.sql | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 > dump_utf8.sql
```

Then I need to remove `CREATE TABLE (…) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` with this command:

```
cat dump_utf8.sql | replace " DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" "" > dump_utf8_formatted.sql
```

Comment: There's no source code.  Maybe this question should be moved to _Software Recommendations_ instead.

Comment: Why do you need to "convert database file into UTF-8"?  And do you mean "file" or "tables"?  Tables can be converted without dumping, but we need more details, such as `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and whether the data is correctly stored in some other encoding.

Comment: The database currently in `latin1` with Hebrew characters and need to be converted into `UTF-8` as the correct encoding, and it can be done via **mysqldump**. There is another way? I edited my question and added the commands I tried to run. Thanks.

Comment: latin1 does not handle Hebrew.  So, what is the encoding for the Hebrew characters?  Get it in HEX.

Comment: If necessary, load as latin1, then let's figure out how to change to utf8.  After loading, do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` to get a sample of the Hebrew characters.  I would guess you need the 2-step ALTER, but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Tell `mysqldump` what character set to use in the output.  It will do the conversion on the fly, without extra steps.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html says

> Column values are converted to the character set specified by the
>   `--default-character-set` option.

Also, you should have `--set-charset` (or `--opt`) so that when you import it later, it will correctly know the encoding of the characters in the file.